# plot_ly doesn´t show graph in Shiny app

Tags: shiny, plotly

I have a problem with shiny app. My shinyapp doesn´t show graph. I have this code. I dont see my graph in shiny enviroment, i see in rstudio viewer.

```
## app.R ##

    library("shiny")

setwd('C:/work')




ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(

    fluidRow(
      plotOutput("plot", height = 250)),
      box(
        title = "Controls",
        selectInput("select",label="Select",
                    choices=setNames(as.list(data$prov), data$prov))
      )
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output){

  output$plot<- renderPlot({
    plot_ly(bbdd,x=~prov, y=~number, type='bar')

  })
}



shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Its my first app in shiny, dont kill me!

thanks

Comment: Where is the data `bbdd` which should be the data for you plot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change plotOutput and renderPlot to plot**ly**Output and renderPlot**ly** respectively. you also need to load the plotly package and your data for the plot.